# For which values of a and b is the system consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

```
x1 + x2 + 2x3       = a,
x1 + x2 − x3 + x4   = 1,
     x2 + bx3 + x4  = 5.
```

I get this after Gaussian Elimination:

```
x1 + x2 + 2x3      = a
     x2 + bx3 + x4 = 5
           x3 - x4/3 = (a-1)/3
and x4=x4.
```

But I don't really know how to move on from this.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you set $x_4=0$?

Comment: @Moo, LoL, For which values of "7" or "1" is this question and the linked question consistent?

Comment: @Moo, they are all sevens.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, but why then are some of the ones written with just a straight vertical line?

Comment: Swell.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

I get:

```
x1 = (a+ab-b-13)/3
x2 = (b-ab+15)/3
x3 = (a-1)/3
```

I've been trying to draw a conclusion but I think I'm stuck.

x1,x2 and x3 can be zero as far as I know, does this mean that a and b could be any number?

Comment: You are supposed to include your attempt in the question itself.